# Remove top bar header

Tags: css, headers

I'm having trouble removing some content from a website which I have taken over.

There is a bar above the header which isn't a navigation bar and I am having trouble removing it. I was able to remove some of the styles from the CSS but I can't see an option to remove it without taking away the whole header.

I'm using the Layerswp theme.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Use the developer toolbar, select the bar and  set the CSS property (display) to none. Otherwise, post the link of the website.

Comment: Ditto use the developer toolbar to inspect the bar you're trying to remove and look at the CSS classes and IDs. Hopefully you can then search for those, or code that looks like it's generating them, in your theme and database to work out where this is coming from. But as it stands there's not a lot we can do to help you.